# TSQL best practise defining reusable variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query I want to adapt.

```
SELECT t1.[Field1], t1.[Field2]     
,CASE
    WHEN t1.[Field3] LIKE '%SOMETEXT1%' THEN 'X1'
    WHEN t1.[Field3] LIKE '%SOMETEXT2%' THEN 'X2'
    WHEN t1.[Field3] LIKE '%SOMETEXT3%' THEN 'X3'
    WHEN t1.[Field3] LIKE '%SOMETEXT4%' THEN 'X4'
    WHEN t1.[Field3] LIKE '%SOMETEXT5%' THEN 'X5'
END
FROM Table1 t1
```

I want to clean `t1.[Field3]` as

```
LEFT(t1.[Field3], LEN(t1.[Field3]) - CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(t1.[Field3]))) AS CleanField3
```

Is it possible to define this as a variable so I can write something like the following

```
SELECT t1.[Field1], t1.[Field2]     
,CASE
    WHEN CleanField3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT1%' THEN 'X1'
    WHEN CleanField3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT2%' THEN 'X2'
    WHEN CleanField3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT3%' THEN 'X3'
    WHEN CleanField3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT4%' THEN 'X4'
    WHEN CleanField3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT5%' THEN 'X5'
END
FROM Table1 t1
```

instead of

```
SELECT t1.[Field1], t1.[Field2]     
,CASE
    WHEN LEFT(t1.[Field3], LEN(t1.[Field3]) - CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(t1.[Field3]))) LIKE '%SOMETEXT1%' THEN 'X1'
    WHEN LEFT(t1.[Field3], LEN(t1.[Field3]) - CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(t1.[Field3]))) LIKE '%SOMETEXT2%' THEN 'X2'
    WHEN LEFT(t1.[Field3], LEN(t1.[Field3]) - CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(t1.[Field3]))) LIKE '%SOMETEXT3%' THEN 'X3'
    WHEN LEFT(t1.[Field3], LEN(t1.[Field3]) - CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(t1.[Field3]))) LIKE '%SOMETEXT4%' THEN 'X4'
    WHEN LEFT(t1.[Field3], LEN(t1.[Field3]) - CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(t1.[Field3]))) LIKE '%SOMETEXT5%' THEN 'X5'
END
FROM Table1 t1
```

I have looked at using variables but can't see a way to make them work this way? eg https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with variables, you can do it with a subquery though:

```
SELECT  T.[Field1]
,       T.[Field2] 
,       CASE
            WHEN CleanField3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT1%' THEN 'X1'
            WHEN CleanField3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT2%' THEN 'X2'
            WHEN CleanField3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT3%' THEN 'X3'
            WHEN CleanField3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT4%' THEN 'X4'
            WHEN CleanField3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT5%' THEN 'X5'
        END
FROM    (
            SELECT  t1.[Field1]
            ,       t1.[Field2]     
            ,       LEFT(t1.[Field3], LEN(t1.[Field3]) - CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(t1.[Field3]))) CleanField3
            FROM    Table1 t1
        ) T
```

Comment: This would be the easiest way imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cross apply` to avoid subquery:

```
SELECT t1.[Field1], t1.[Field2]     
,CASE
    WHEN f3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT1%' THEN 'X1'
    WHEN f3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT2%' THEN 'X2'
    WHEN f3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT3%' THEN 'X3'
    WHEN f3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT4%' THEN 'X4'
    WHEN f3 LIKE '%SOMETEXT5%' THEN 'X5'
END
FROM Table1 t1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT f3 = LEFT(t1.[Field3], LEN(t1.[Field3]) - CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(t1.[Field3])))) Q
```

Comment: I am curious how using cross apply avoided a subquery here. Your cross apply IS a subquery. The bigger issue is that your subquery is not valid. I think you took out LEFT.

Comment: @Sean Lange a statement is a subquery when it has `FROM` clause. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx